# measure of reliability for an SSD drive?

Tags: ssd

Other than fitting into the slot for the current HDD drive, I understand that the main consideration to take into account when choosing an SSD drive on a laptop is reliability. How is reliability measured for SSD drives? Where can I find that information in the manufacturer's specifications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the time you will only find the mean time between between failure ([Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTBF))

Though a more accurate number is the amount of data that can be written to the SSD before completely wearing out. It is uncommon for manufacturers to tell us this number, though some do it.

> Note: by the way, some manufacturers give the total amount of data written to the drive as one of the drive lifetime indicators. For example, Intel guarantees that the total of about 37 TB of data will be written to X25-M drives (20 GB per day for 5 years: “The drive will have a minimum of 5 years of useful life under typical client workloads with up to 20 GB host writes per day.”).
>
> Source: http://ssd-life.com/eng/how.html

Answer (score 1):

You can measure reliability with this tool - [SsdReady](http://www.ssdready.com/ssdready/) (if you use Windows) before actual ssd usage. Or with [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653). Here is a very good post at SuperUser blogs about SSD - [Maximizing lifetime of your SSD](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/10/maximizing-the-lifetime-of-your-ssd/).